# In IOS how to read the Resouce bundle file

Tags: ios

in Object c we read bundle resouce like these:
 `pathName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"filetype"];`

then :

`[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]`

but now I would like to read the resouce content in a `C++` file,but do not want any `objective-c` code any other means?

Comment: You can do it with `objc_msgSend()` but I doubt that's really what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CoreFoundation, which is purely C-based. Check out [Accessing a Bundle's Contents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW1) and the [CFBundle reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFBundleRef).